# Performance of Separation of Multipage TIFF

Tags: c#, image, tiff

I need to separate Multipage TIFF files. The input folder contains 100 TIFF files. The time taken for 100 TIFF files is 1.40 minutes. Each TIFF file contains two pages. Is there any way to improve performance, and is there a way to speed up the process?

```
               static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                   string input = @"D:\testSplit\input\";
                string output = @"D:\testSplit\output\out";
                DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(input);        
                FileInfo[] DispatchFiles = dir1.GetFiles();
                if (DispatchFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo aFile in DispatchFiles)
                    {
                        string files = input + aFile.Name;

                        if (File.Exists(files))
                        {
                            Split(files, output);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


            public static List<string> Split(string InputFilePath, string OutputPath)
            {
                List<string> splitFileNames = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    //Get the frame dimension list from the image of the file and 
                      Image tiffImage = Image.FromFile(InputFilePath);                            
                    //get the globally unique identifier (GUID)        
                    Guid objGuid = tiffImage.FrameDimensionsList[0];       
                    //create the frame dimension 
                    FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);
                    //Gets the total number of frames in the .tiff file 
                    int noOfPages = tiffImage.GetFrameCount(dimension);        
                    if (noOfPages == 1)
                    {
                        splitFileNames.Add(InputFilePath);
                        tiffImage.Dispose();
                        return splitFileNames;
                    }
                    string filName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(InputFilePath);
                    string fileExtention = Path.GetExtension(InputFilePath);

                    ImageCodecInfo encodeInfo = null;
                    ImageCodecInfo[] imageEncoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                    for (int j = 0; j < imageEncoders.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (imageEncoders[j].MimeType == "image/tiff")
                        {
                            encodeInfo = imageEncoders[j];
                            break;
                        }

                    // Save the tiff file in the output directory. 
                    if (!Directory.Exists(OutputPath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(OutputPath);
                    foreach (Guid guid in tiffImage.FrameDimensionsList)
                    {
                        for (int index = 0; index < noOfPages; index++)
                        {
                            FrameDimension currentFrame = new FrameDimension(guid);

                            tiffImage.SelectActiveFrame(currentFrame, index);

                            string outPath = string.Concat(OutputPath, filName, "-P", index + 1, fileExtention);

                            tiffImage.Save(outPath, encodeInfo, null);

                            splitFileNames.Add(outPath);
                        }
                    }

                    tiffImage.Dispose();            
                    return splitFileNames;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return splitFileNames;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

A [parallel foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) loop may get you where you need to be.

```
FileInfo[] DispatchFiles = dir1.GetFiles();
Parallel.ForEach(DispatchFiles, aFile =>
{
    string files = input + aFile.Name;
    if (File.Exists(files))
    {
        Split(files, output);
    }
}
```

With parallel processing you may run into some shared resource issues, but if each processing is fully independent of each other, it should improve your performance.

If you need to limit the number of threads that the loop creates, check out the [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) property.

Comment: thanks for for replay i want to improve performance in the  split method can please suggest   Image tiffImage = Image.FromFile(InputFilePath),tiffImage.Save(outPath, encodeInfo, null) consumes  more time

Comment: When you depend on an opaque function provided by someone else, you can't know what it's doing. It could be doing a full decode and re-encode of each page. An efficient library (like mine) can do the job in the amount of time it takes to read+write the data to disk.